# How to publish custom artifacts in sbt 1.0.x

Tags: sbt, debian, nexus

We had some custom code in build.sbt to publish debian binaries to nexus for sbt 0.13

```
lazy val distrib = com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys.dist

publish := (publish) dependsOn distrib

publishLocal := (publishLocal) dependsOn distrib

artifact in distHack ~= { (art: Artifact) => art.copy(`type` = "deb", extension = "deb") }

val distHack = TaskKey[File]("dist-hack", "Hack to publish dist")

val distHackSettings = Seq[Setting[_]](
  distHack := {
    val packageName = "%s_%s_all" format(normalizedName.value, version.value)
    target.value / (packageName + ".deb")
  }
) ++ Seq(addArtifact(artifact in distHack, distHack).settings: _*)

seq(distHackSettings: _*)

//addArtifact(artifact in distHack, distHack)

publishArtifact in (Compile, packageBin) := false 

publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false 

publishArtifact in (Compile, packageSrc) := false
```

But, it does not work under sbt 1.x.
Does anybody have any pointers to proceed? 
Note: I have read through all the related questions on stackoverflow already.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You use the following code

```
lazy val distrib = com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys.dist

artifact in (Compile, packageBin) := {
  val previous: Artifact = (artifact in (Compile, packageBin)).value
  previous.withExtension("deb")
}

publish := (publish dependsOn distrib).value

publishLocal := (publishLocal dependsOn distrib).value

publishArtifact in (Compile, packageBin) := true

publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false

publishArtifact in (Compile, packageSrc) := false

publishArtifact in Test := false
```

Comment: It would help if you can explain your answer.